# CSS: Como fazer a animação de transição funcionar apenas quando o mouse passar sobre o elemento

Tags: css

Quando você coloca transition em um objeto, toda vez que você atualiza a página, aquela animação/transição ocorre. Tem como deixar exclusivamente pra ação que você quer? Por exemplo o :hover?

Eu sei que posso fazer o css desta maneira:

```
#button{
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px;
}
#button:hover{
   background-color: #000;
   transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
```

Porém dessa maneira só funciona ao passar o mouse, a transição não vai ocorrer quando tiver a saída do mouse sobre o objeto. Sem ser javascript, tem como deixar exclusivamente para uma determinada ação?

Comment: Coloca o transaction sem o Hover e aplica a mudança desejada no Hover que já funciona

Answer (score -2):

Coloca um `transition: background-color .5s ease;`

Se colocar a transição apenas no hover ele vai ter a animação apenas quando passar o mouse, mas se colocar a transição no elemento em sí tipo...

```
element{
transition: background-color .5s ease;
}
```

Essa animação vai ocorrer sempre que passar o mouse ou remover o mouse de cima do elemento, o mais legal é que funciona com :focus e :active, na real, funciona pra muita coisa alem disso.